# Using NScanner to parse CSV File to Dictionary Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsscanner

I've created an iPhone app that has a dictionary array of locations (lat,long,point). I created the array by manually entering each value.

```
myLocationArray = @[
                 @{
                   kStation : @"1",
                   kLatitude : @( 41.656467),
                   kLongitude : @(-81.277963)
                   },
                 @{
                   kStation : @"2",
                   kLatitude : @(41.657118),
                   kLongitude : @(-81.276545)
                   },
                 @{
                   kStation : @"3",
                   kLatitude : @(41.658493),
                   kLongitude : @(-81.273542)
                   },
                  ...
```

This is good and works but now I want to create this array programmatically by getting the data from a .CSV file. I have a .CSV file (TestCSV.csv) that looks like this.

```
41.656467,-81.277963,27200
41.657118,-81.276545,27650
41.658493,-81.273542,28631.5
41.660728,-81.268547,30195
41.661830,-81.266065,30991
41.662828,-81.263819,31700
41.663677,-81.261962,32300
41.664578,-81.259909,32950
41.666210,-81.256312,34100
41.666921,-81.254708,34605
41.668043,-81.252191,35400
41.669044,-81.250043,36099
```

I'd like to create myLocationArray (with formatting as shown) by parsing TestCSV.csv using NScanner. I've set up to parse the my data file.

```
NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestCSV" ofType: @"csv"];

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if (!fileString) {
NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
}

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
```

I need help from here though. I've looked at many examples but it seems like this is where I need some code custom to my application. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're bothering with a scanner at all, seeing as your structure is so simple and predictable. Start with an empty NSMutableArray. You can split the file into lines like this:

```
NSArray *lines = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Now enumerate that array. For each line, you can split the line at the commas:

```
NSArray *nums = [oneLine componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

The array `nums` is an array of three NSString values. For the first two items of the array, convert them to doubles with `doubleValue` and wrap that in an NSNumber. Make the NSDictionary for that line and add it to the NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually already looking into this option. Please take a look at my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499180/create-a-custom-formatted-dictionary-array-from-csv-file-of-data. Specifically, Anupdas' answer is what I'm trying out and having an issue with.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to re-invent the wheel, as there are a couple of pitfalls in the CSV file format (which is not even especially well defined).

There are for instance the special cases of newlines and commas within a field. Any algorithm based on just splitting by lines and commas is going produce incorrect results given such input. Also notice that Excel doesn't always use a comma as a separator, depending on the locale.

Use a library like [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser), which will cover those pitfalls.